Is it possible to configure `kubectl exec` to behavior the same way as `ssh` when there is a client disconnect?
Empirically, it looks like kubectl exec and ssh behave differently on disconnects of the client.
I performed the following experiments.
SSH
# Terminal 1
ssh <random_host_in_aws> 
bash -c 'sleep 600000'

Terminal 2
kill -9 <pid_of_ssh_process>
ssh <random_host_in_aws> 
ps aux | grep sleep
# No sleep processes

Kubectl Exec
# Terminal 1
kubectl exec ...
bash -c 'sleep 600000'

# Terminal 2
kill -9 <pid_of_kubectl_process>
kubectl exec ...
ps aux | grep sleep
# Sleep process is still around.

Is there some magic configuration in the Kubernetes cluster or client that will force it to behave the same way as ssh in the face of client disconnects?

SSH and Kubectl are quite different.
With the SSH protocol, there is a connection between the SSH client and the SSH server, there's TCP traffic going back and forth, part of that traffic is a shell session which happens to run bash in the case you described, and some ping/pong traffic too. When this TCP connection breaks (because you kill the SSH client) and the SSH server no longer receives communication from the SSH client, it will terminate the shell session, sending a "hang up" signal to any processes inside that session, thus terminating your bash shell and the sleep process spawned inside that shell.
With kubectl exec, you're interactively streaming your terminal to the container terminal (kubectl -> API server -> Kubelet -> runc-exec), and any process you run there, will continue running, regardless of whether you're still streaming or stopped streaming by killing the client kubectl process. Control sequences such as Ctrl+C are also streamed to the container.
I don't think it's possible to achieve SSH-like behavior with kubectl exec without some ping/pong scripts. If you need to kill a running process inside the container, finding its pid and killing it inside the container is probably the way to go.
Some related/similar discussion here about this problem: https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/3359
